# Adding values in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I can't seem to figure out how to add the values in a for loop. I'm supposed to get an output like this:

> ```
> How many numbers?
> 3     //user inputs numbers desired.
> number please
> 1
> 2
> 3
> Total is 6
> ```

Any help would be much obliged!

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
public class AddNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 1;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many numbers?");
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i <= n; i++){
            System.out.println ("number please");
            int c = scan.nextInt();

            //stuck

        }        
        System.out.println("Total is " + sum);
}
}
```

Comment: Just add `sum += c;` in your loop
Also your loop should be `for(int i=0; i < n; i++)` **not** `<=n`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm very inexperienced with coding java.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
    System.out.println ("number please");
    int c = scan.nextInt();
    sum =sum+c; // add this

 }
```

Comment: Invalid answer! You've repeated the mistake which _OP_ has done. `<=` is wrong, it should be only `<`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum=0;
    System.out.println("How many numbers?");
    int count = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("number please");

    // This is what you need to change
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        sum += scan.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Total is " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one variable outside the `for` loop and add your values to this variable to calculate total:

```
int n = scan.nextInt();
int total = 0;
for(int i=0; i <= n; i++){
    System.out.println ("number please");
    int c = scan.nextInt();
    //stuck
    total += c;
}
```

Comment: Invalid answer! You've repeated the mistake which _OP_ has done. `<=` is wrong, it should be only `<`

Comment: @R.J but he's not stuck there, though you are right, that is a logical mistake by OP.